# send ajax get request to node, response is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, get

I have a Node server running a single web page. That page has a contact form, with a send button.

If i click send, the following code will run:

```
$('.contactsend').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/contact",
        dataType: "jsonp"
    })  .done(function(data) {
            alert( data );
        })
        .fail(function() {
            alert( "error" );
        })
        .always(function() {
            alert( "complete" );
        });
})
```

This far it seems OK, the page is reached.

This is what the middleware does:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send({test:'test'})
  //res.send('test')
});
```

After sending this, the webpage shows the following message:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

If I dont send `json`, but the string instead, the message is like

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: test is not defined
```

Comment: there was something causing problems with response without standards. you can use `res.json` instead `res.send`.

Comment: I changed my `res.send` to `res.jsonp`, that worked. If i use `dataType: "json"` I am getting troubled by the `access origin` -peep-

Comment: you can send response without changing response type but you have to replace special characters but it's not true way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The client is expecting jsonp, but you are sending json.

Try this:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.jsonp({test:'test'});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to overcome the cross-domain restriction, you can use `res.json()`. Try:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.json({test:'test'});  
});
```

And change `ajax.dataType` to `json`:

```
$.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/contact",
    dataType: "json"
    // ...
```

Comment: Gives the same result :(

Comment: you need to change ajax data type to `json` too

Comment: Thanks that should indeed do it, but then I get troubled by `access origin` stuff